# In Skyfall, why did M order Eve to "take the shot?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall

Why was it so important for M that Eve take a risky shot that ended up killing Bond,  until he turned out to be faking it?     Was the bad guy such an immediate threat that it was worth losing Bond?

Comment: "killing Bond"? Last time I checked he was still alive.

Comment: "Killing Bond"? Yeah, I was into them before they got all emo and trendy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not so much that the bad guy was dangerous. It's more that the hard disk he's stealing contains the names of hundreds of secret agents in active undercover operations. It's sacrificing one life to save hundreds.

Comment: This answer suggests M knew Bond would get shot, which was merely collateral damage and not her intent. It's much more like "putting one life at risk" to save hundreds.

Comment: @hexparrot: In the movie, M knew Bond would most probably get shot (not the same thing as being certain but that's like saying dropping the atom bomb on Hiroshima would most probably detonate a nuclear explosion - it wasn't 100% certain then either but certain enough that you assume it would happen). M knew because Eve said that she's got a firing solution (meaning that she can hit the target) but it's not clean (meaning that she would hit someone else as well). The only logical collateral damage was Bond.

Answer (score 4):

Two reasons:

1. Because movie lines are more and more picked from a grab-bag of the same phrases, and unfortunately, "Take the shot" is one of them.
2. The info was meant to be very important, and the value of all the agents' lives was worth more than that of one aging agent. Of course by the end of the movie we all know that there's no school like the old school, but according to the way of thinking at the start of the film the right thing to do was to sacrifice the old chap!